# Como retornar table em react uma list criada em spring

Tags: react, spring-boot

Estou precisando retornar no meu projeto em **React** dentro de uma tabela, uma classe "NivelCarreira" que é relacionada a uma outra classe "carreira", onde "NivelCarreira" tem relacionamento **ManyToOne**(SpringBoot) e é criada em uma **List<>** - Uma carreira tem vários níveis de carreira, resumidamente.
Só que infelizmente, não estou conseguindo dar o get nesta classe e retornar em uma table.
URL GET oriunda de projeto **SpringBoot**: /projeto/carreiras/{idCarreira}/nivelcarreira/

Exemplo das tentativas de table para retornar o nivelCarreira:

```
return <table className="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>Classe</tr>
                <tr>Nível</tr>
                <tr>Interstício</tr>
                <tr>Unidade Interstício</tr>
                <tr>Remuneração</tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {this.props.itens.map((nivelCarreira) => {
                    console.log(nivelCarreira)
                        return (
                            <tr key={nivelCarreira.idNivelCarreira}>
                                <td>{nivelCarreira.classe}</td>
                                <td>{nivelCarreira.nivel}</td>
                                <td>{nivelCarreira.intersticio}</td>
                                <td>{nivelCarreira.unidade_intersticio}</td>
                                <td>{nivelCarreira.remuneracao}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Outra tentativa:

```
return <table className="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>Classe</tr>
                <tr>Nível</tr>
                <tr>Interstício</tr>
                <tr>Unidade Interstício</tr>
                <tr>Remuneração</tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {this.props.itens.map((nivelCarreira) => {
                    console.log(nivelCarreira)
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{this.props.carreira.nivelCarreira.classe}</td>
                                <td>{this.props.carreira.nivelCarreira.nivel}</td>
                                <td>{this.props.carreira.nivelCarreira.intersticio}</td>
                                <td>{this.props.carreira.nivelCarreira.unidade_intersticio}</td>
                                <td>{this.props.carreira.nivelCarreira.remuneracao}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Método get para listar os níveis de carreira:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{idCarreira}/nivelcarreira/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<NivelCarreira> listarNiveisCarreira(@PathVariable("idCarreira") Long idCarreira) {       
        try {
            return this.cargoService.buscarCarreiraPorId(idCarreira).getNivelCarreira();
        } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new NaoEncontrado("Não existe níveis de carreira cadastradas!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você precisa é utilizar axios, é bem simples e bem tranquilo de usar, segue o [link](https://www.devmedia.com.br/consumindo-uma-api-com-react-js-e-axios/42900), espero que ajude.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/380142)

Comment: Consegui responder, era um problema nas chaves do mapeamento de URL